# What is the proper way to reinitialize weights of some layers in tensforflow2?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

What is the proper way to reinitialize weights of some layers in TF2?

There exists a valid method for TF1:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51727616/11836236

and some workaround for TF2:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57826239/11836236
but this solution does not utilize the initializers that are specified in each layers.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with tf 2.3.0: (edited from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63439614/14263297))

```
for layer in model.layers:         
    if hasattr(layer, 'kernel_initializer') and \
            hasattr(layer, 'bias_initializer'):
        layer.set_weights([layer.kernel_initializer(shape=np.asarray(layer.kernel.shape)), \
            layer.bias_initializer(shape=np.asarray(layer.bias.shape))])
```

Hope it might help.

Comment: Thanks. This seems exactly what I was looking for. However, I don't need the solution anymore so I won't confirm it right now.