# How to make sure that Keras model weights are initialised randomly every-time the model is fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am training a Keras model for my data. I have to split the data into 3 parts and I am calling the same keras model for each split and trying to fit and predict consecutively.

I have a suspicion that every-time I call the model the model weights remain the same after reaching convergence from last training. And the next model called starts minimising the error from its previous state. I want that each time the model is trained, it starts to fit the data from a different random weights initialisation. Because all of my 3 splits are subset of the same dataset and I don't want any data leakage into the model due to seeing the split data beforehand while training.

Can I know if it is reinitialising the weights every-time the model is fit. And if not how can I do so?

here is how my code looks like

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_dim=77, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(512, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(512, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))


# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')


model()
# evaluate model
history = model.fit(scaler.transform(X_train_high), y_train_high,
                    batch_size=128,
                    epochs=5)
results = model.evaluate(scaler.transform(X_train_high), y_train_high, batch_size=128)
print('High test loss, test acc:', results)

# evaluate model
history = model.fit(scaler.transform(X_train_medium), y_train_medium,
                    batch_size=128,
                    epochs=5)
results = model.evaluate(scaler.transform(X_train_medium), y_train_medium, batch_size=128)
print(' Medium test loss, test acc:', results)

# evaluate model
history = model.fit(scaler.transform(X_train_low), y_train_low,
                    batch_size=128,
                    epochs=5)
results = model.evaluate(scaler.transform(X_train_low), y_train_low, batch_size=128, epochs=5)
print('Low test loss, test acc:', results)
```

Comment: Try to load initialized model weights every time you need to run `model.fit`. ([See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43957826/4715661))

Comment: you have to compile it again fi you wan't it to start from as it it was never trained

Comment: after you do `model.compile()` you can run `model.get_weights()` to see your model weights. Might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model will keep its weight until you redefine one.

```
def define_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(512, input_dim=77, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(512, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(512, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1))

model=define_model()
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')


# evaluate model
history = model.fit(scaler.transform(X_train_high), y_train_high,
                    batch_size=128,
                    epochs=5)
results = model.evaluate(scaler.transform(X_train_high), y_train_high, batch_size=128)
print('High test loss, test acc:', results)

model=define_model()

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
# evaluate model
history = model.fit(scaler.transform(X_train_medium), y_train_medium,
                    batch_size=128,
                    epochs=5)
results = model.evaluate(scaler.transform(X_train_medium), y_train_medium, batch_size=128)
print(' Medium test loss, test acc:', results)
```

You can check by `model.get_weights`.